# Getting error in checkboxes

Tags: java, swing, exception, fonts

I am extremely new to Java. I tried to create a checkbox program that will italicize and bold text on click. I have completed the coding but getting error and don't know how to resolve it.Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class checkboxes extends JFrame {

private JTextField tf;
private JCheckBox boldbox;
private JCheckBox italicbox;

public checkboxes(){

    super("This is a checkbox");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    tf = new JTextField("This is a text",20);
    tf.setFont=(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14));
    add(tf);
    boldbox = new JCheckBox("Bold text");
    italicbox = new JCheckBox("Italicize Text");
    add(boldbox);
    add(italicbox);


    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    boldbox.addItemListener(handler);
    italicbox.addItemListener(handler);
}

private HandlerClass implements ItemListener{

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
        Font font = null;

        if(boldbox.isSelected() && italicbox.isSelected())
            font = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC,14);
        else if(boldbox.isSelected())
            font = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,14);
        else if(italicbox.isSelected())
            font = new Font("Serif",Font.ITALIC,14);
        else
            font = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14);
        tf.setFont(font);
        }
}   }
```

I am getting error on this line:

```
tf.setFont=(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14));
```

The error says:
**setFont cannot be resolved or is not a field**

Please guide me what's the error in my code. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very basic syntax error, so is unlikely to help anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this `tf.setFont=(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14));` to

```
tf.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14));
```

because `JTextField#setFont()` is a method and you can't use an assignment operator on it!

Answer (score 3):

it should be, and below is a valid way of passing parameters to the method

```
tf.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14));
```

When you said

`tf.setFont=` Java assumed that `tf` has `setFont` public field, which it (`JTextField`) does not have